# java non blocking cache implementation

Tags: java, nonblocking

(please note i cannot use external libraries for the cache).

---may it can be done using the stream API? ---

i need to implement a cache, it's has 1 key property:

If the cache is asked for a key that it doesn't contain, it should fetch the data using an externally provided function that reads the data from another source (database or similar).

i've started to create a basic skelaton code:

```
public interface ICache<K,V> {
}

interface IDataSource<K,V> {
   void put(K key, V value);
   V get(K key);
}


public class Cache<K,V> implements ICache<K,V> {
   Map<K,V> cache = new HashMap<>();
   IDataSource<K,V> dataSource;


public Cache(IDataSource<K,V> dataSrc) {
    dataSource = dataSrc;
}

//may it change to a future? how it can be done?
public V getAsync(K key) {   
    if (cache.containsKey(key)) {
        return cache.get(key);
    }
    else {
        //do some async op
    }
}
}
```

can you advice?

do u think it's need more features?

Comment: You don't appear to have considered concurrency / multi-threading.

Comment: If you want to do this asynchronously, your `getAsync()` cannot return the desired value. Instead, as a parameter you should pass some listener that gets called as soon as the data is available (which will be immediately in case the data is already present in the cache).

Comment: @RobertKock Or have it return a `Future<V>`.

Answer (score 2):

In reality what you are writing is a lazy evaluator. You are providing a `Supplier` for the value, without computing it the first time. The moment someone asks for your value you compute it and return it, memoizing (caching) it for future use.

Have a look at Vavr's `Lazy` class, it is doing precisely this (but for a single value). You can take some ideas from what that is doing, and also some extra utility methods like checking if it was already computed.

https://github.com/vavr-io/vavr/blob/master/vavr/src/main/java/io/vavr/Lazy.java

Another option is to simply use `ConcurrentHashMap`. It provides methods to safely (atomically) update values if they are not in the map.

If you want it to be asynchronous you need to introduce some `ExecutorService` or use `CompletableFuture` (with your own `ExecutorService` or the default thread pool that is used by parallel streams etc.). For example:

```
public class Cache<K,V> implements ICache<K,V> {
   Map<K,V> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
   IDataSource<K,V> dataSource;

   public Cache(IDataSource<K,V> dataSrc) {
     dataSource = dataSrc;
   }

   // async non-blocking call
   public CompletableFuture<V> getAsync(K key) {   
     return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> get(key));
   }

   // blocking call
   public V get(K key) {   
     //computeIfAbsent is atomic and threadsafe, in case multiple CompletableFutures try this in parallel
     return cache.computeIfAbsent(key, (k) -> dataSource.get(k));
   }
}
```

If you also wanted to have an async direct cache and datasource update you could do something like:

```
  public CompletableFuture<Void> putAsync(K key, V value) {
    return  CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
      synchronized (cache) {
        dataSource.put(key, value);
        cache.put(key, value);
      }
    }
  }
```

Although honestly I would avoid having 2 entrypoints to update the `dataSource` (the cache and the dataSource directly). Also it is difficult to make this completely thread safe without having the `synchronized` (which blocks concurrent cache puts completely from happening in parallel, even if the key is different).

Comment: how i can supply same behavior for put? @jbx?

Comment: @user10776203 I am not sure what you want to achieve with `put`. `computeIfAbsent()` is automatically asking the `dataSource` if the value does not exist already in the `Map`, and populating it in the `Map` as part of the process before returning the value. So it is like a _"if present just do get, if absent compute it, put it in the map and return it"_.

Comment: no i mean if u want only to put an item in the cache, casuing also to propogate into the datasource...

Comment: meaning that for putAsync

Comment: I wouldn't really do that, because you will risk having different entry points to the datasource and race conditions. I would keep the cache the _slave_ of the datasource. If you want to populate the datasource do it separately through its put. When you ask the cache, and it doesn't have that value, it will automatically get it.

Comment: I added an example for `putAsync()`, although as I said, I wouldn't really recommend going through that route, unless you are going to close off the `dataSource` updates from other places.